# Android Volley send Array as a param along with String

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to send data to the server, Here I am unable to find the way to send both String and Array at a time in a single request.

I can send the array like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
jsonParams.put("names", my_names_list);
```

And also I can send String like:

```
Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
jsonParams.put("user_id", userId);
```

but how to send both at a time?

like:

```
Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
jsonParams.put("user_id", userId);
jsonParams.put("names", my_names_list); // here it is expecting String but I want to send array of strings to server
```

the expected JSON request should be like:

```
{
"user_id": "1",
"names" : ["abc, "cdf", "efg"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can merge the string and array into a single json and then send the json to the server.Example

```
public class Member
{ 
  private String name;
  private List<String> skills;

  //getter and setter at lower
}
```

Use the GSON library for make this model class to json.

```
Member mem = createjsonobject();
Gson gson=new Gson();
String json=gson.toJson(mem);

//Pass this json to the server and at server side you can seperate the string and array  

private static Member createjsonObject()
{
  Member member= new Member();
  member.setName("Rishabh");

  List<String> skill=new ArrayList<>();
  skill.add("Java");
  skill.add("C#");
  skill.add("Android");

  member.setSkills(skill);
  return member;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll do it now

Comment: Thank you Shlendra i am just 3rd year computer science student.

Comment: Great,  I know this process before but the question is different I wanna send String and Array in Map in Volley without using Gson, but for now I went with the solution as you suggested

Comment: please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206258/how-to-add-list-into-params-of-volley-android

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem like this-

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            JSONArray words_ar = new JSONArray();
            for(int i=0;i<exercise.getWord_list().size();i++){
                JSONObject word_ob = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    word_ob.put("id",(i+1)+"");
                    word_ob.put("learn",exercise.getWord_list().get(i).getLearn_str());
                    word_ob.put("native",exercise.getWord_list().get(i).getNative_str());
                    words_ar.put(word_ob);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user", prefs.getUserId()+"");
            params.put("title", exercise.getTitle());
            params.put("words", words_ar+"");
            return params;
        }
```

Comment: you're welcome. Hopefully this may resolve your problem.

Comment: but I don't have any key-value pairs for my array list, pls check my updated question

Comment: Try - JSONArray words_ar = new JSONArray(your_list);

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: If I did like you said `JSONArray words_ar = new JSONArray(your_list);` but am getting the list in double quotes like `"["asdf"]"` in the request.

Comment: I tried iterating map as - 

for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : params.entrySet())
                    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() +
                            ", Value = " + entry.getValue());

and it gives me an array

Comment: Well in PHP this request can be easily decoded with the help of  json_decode()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169641/discussion-between-shylendra-madda-and-chirag-jain).

Comment: @Shylendra Medda I have written something in that chat have you checked that.

Comment: Yeah, I replied too.

Comment: its not work for me please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206258/how-to-add-list-into-params-of-volley-android

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom JSONObject. For your above example request, you can create a JSON object as below

```
    try {
        String[] names = {"abc", "cdf", "efg"};
        String userId = "user_id";
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for(String n : names) {
            jsonArray.put(n);
        }

        JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
        jsonParams.put("names", jsonArray);
        jsonParams.put("userId", userId);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: but I don't have any key-value pairs for my array list, pls check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

try this one ; put the names in array than:

`for(int i = 0;i<yourArrayLength;i++){`

`params.put("names"+i, my_names_list[i]);`

`}`

hope it will help

Comment: sorry but its not working in my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206258/how-to-add-list-into-params-of-volley-android?noredirect=1#comment89393472_51206258

Comment: please help me if you know how can i send list of string in the params of volley android